# Better approach to log the calls to the action methods in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logging

I want to log the calls to the action methods which is a better way, shall i use the actionfilterattribute or override the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action filter seems better and more reusable approach. You won't need to override each controller in which you wanted to log calls.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Also, please let me know if this system of logging calls to urls is possible via Microsoft Enterprise Library and any link reference so that i can read about the implementation.

Comment: Is there a pluggable and configurable option that i can choose from MS Enterprise Library for this logging problem?.